# which.max command in R

Tags: r

I wrote a code to compute the amount of second data set when the amount of the first data set is maximum but at the end for some latitude and longitude I got very large number which is not in the first data set. Here is the core of the code:

```
PW.storm <- array(NA,dim=c(length(lon1),length(lat1)))
for (i in 1:length(lon1)){
    for (j in 1:length(lat1)){
        for (k in 1:length(time)){
            t <- time.when.dat1.max <- which.max(abs(dat1[i,j,]))
            PW.storm[i,j] <- abs(dat2[i,j,t])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here? (I heard they typically end with a question mark.)

Comment: Do note the tie-handling properties of `which.max` - read `?which.max` and try `which(x == max(x)` as an alternative if you have ties.

Answer (score 1):

You code suggests you do not understand what is being returned by `which.max`. You have:

```
time.when.dat1.max <- which.max(abs(dat1[i,j,]))
```

That is not the "time when dat1 is max". It is the index in dat1's third dimension under the conditions of i and j. If times were the values in that third dimension then you would need to use this to get the time values:

```
 time.when.dat1.max <- dat1[i,j, which.max(abs(dat1[i,j,]))]
```

If I've guessed wrong about what the dat1 object holds, then you should do a better job of describing the data setup by editing your question.